# How to draw a line on Canvas from top of screen to bottom?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to add a line to my game separating the left and right regions. I added a Gameobject to my Canvas and added the following script to it:

```
public class DrawLine : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Color c1 = Color.red;
    public Color c2 = Color.white;
    Vector3 topPoint;
    Vector3 bottomPoint;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        topPoint = new Vector3(Screen.width / 4, Screen.height);
        bottomPoint = new Vector3(Screen.width / 4, 0);
        LineRenderer lineRenderer = gameObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
        lineRenderer.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Sprites/Default"));
        lineRenderer.widthMultiplier = 2.2f;
        lineRenderer.positionCount = 40;

        // A simple 2 color gradient with a fixed alpha of 1.0f.
        float alpha = 1.0f;
        Gradient gradient = new Gradient();
        gradient.SetKeys(
            new GradientColorKey[] { new GradientColorKey(c1, 0.0f), new GradientColorKey(c2, 1.0f) },
            new GradientAlphaKey[] { new GradientAlphaKey(alpha, 0.0f), new GradientAlphaKey(alpha, 1.0f) }
        );
        lineRenderer.colorGradient = gradient;

        lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, topPoint);
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, bottomPoint);
    }


}
```

When I run the game. A LineRenderer is added to the gameObject with the required colours and width, but there is no line drawn.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested the code you posted and it's working fine. I was originally thinking that the line was being drawn too thin and was going to recommend resizing the line to be larger at the start and end points, but after testing I do see the line being drawn in editor and game.

[image: Here's an image of it being drawn in engine]

If the `LineRenderer` component is being created and you are not able to see the line either editor or game view, then post an image of the inspector for the gameobject that has the `LineRenderer` component at runtime.

---

**Response to your comments**

Using the LineRenderer draws a line at runtime in 3D-Space based on the positions selected in your code when you do the `SetPosition` calls.

When talking about a `Canvas`, I assume you are talking about a **UI Canvas**.

The LineRenderer draws based on the positions you set and not based on the Canvas unless you program it that way.

So, if your camera is not positioned in a location to see the line in front of it then it won't be displayed in the `game view`.

[image: Here's an image show how I have my camera set up to see the line]

Comment: You're right. I can see the line being drawn in Editor but its not visible in the Game window. Ive attached the screenshot to my question, Thanks

Comment: Next question is going to be whether or not your camera is positioned in a location to see the line? The Image you posted looks like your rendered is correct.

Comment: The gameobject to which the linerenderer is added to is added to the Canvas. Shouldnt this be added to the canvas and shown in game?

Comment: Adding some more notes to the end of my Answer above.

Comment: Yes, youre right. When I move the camera all the way away from my game and direct it to the line renderer I can see it in game. But that is giving me no benefit. I want to draw a line on screen . Which it is doing in editor mode but how do I move it in view of the camera?

Comment: judging by this: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1201050/is-there-way-to-have-line-renderer-on-a-canvas.html there is no easy way to draw this line of mine. I just decided to make a thin panel and set position via script